# SBT: How to trigger separate actions when files change in two separate subprojects

Tags: scala, sbt

My `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
val client = project.in(file("client"))

val server = project.in(file("server"))
```

The main project comprises two separate projects, client and server. I would like to develop them simultaneously: I need both of them built and the server running when I'm working. Each project has their own additional build steps: `client` needs a `packageJS` after being compiled, while `server` needs a `container:restart`.

However, doing `~; restartServer; restartClient` from the root directory doesn't do what I want, since it listens to either subproject and always restarts both of them, and in my case causes a restart loop since one subproject dumps files into the other subproject for it to use.

Is there anyway to do this "~restartXXX" in both subprojects simultaneously, so I can edit either of them and it will restart only the edited project?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, it seems like even if there is such a way, restarting the edited project will change the other (since "one subproject dumps files into the other subproject for it to use"), which will restart the other, which will dump files into the original edited project, etc. causing the same loop again. Or is that dependency non-mutual?

Comment: It's non mutual, so only one subproject dumps files into the other but *not* vice versa

Comment: As an addendum, the "dump files into other project thing" isn't really that important. Even if it didn't do that, I would like to have both subprojects watched but only the subproject whose files have changed reload. Reloading both of them is wasteful and expensive (starting and stopping containers is slow-ish).

Comment: Not sure, whether I understand the problem correctly: what do you men by _"do this `~restartXXX` in both subprojects simultaneously"_?
If you just want to run `~restartXXX` in every subproject by one command you can do it with
`; project server; ~restartServer; project root; project client; ~restartClient; project root`

Comment: That would in theory do what I want, but `project root` command will not run until I kill the `~restartServer` command, so that won't work

Comment: I see. Don't know if it helps, but may be [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) plugin can be useful here

Comment: I have the same trouble, and right now forced to use two independent sbt sessions. In one session I start ~restartServer and in another session ~restartClient. Want to know more useful solution. Solution with command `all` does not works as we need since it run BOTH tasks on a change, but we need to run only relevant task.

Comment: Is there any way to make a custom task in perhaps the root project that can figure out which task to run?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried: `~ all restartServer restartClient`.

In sbt 0.13.2-M2 (and I think sbt 0.13.1, but not sure), there is a new `all` command which will run specified tasks in parallel.  Combined with ~, you can ensure you run more than one task on a change.

Comment: Well, what's cool is  0.13.2-M2 is usable now, and I'm trying to get 0.13.2-RC1 out the door now :)

Comment: This solution runs both tasks (`restartServer` and `restartClient`) on every change. But we need to run only relevant task: if server sources was changed then only `restartServer` should be runned, `restartClient` otherwise.